# I get 'undefined' when accessing a json array position

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I am getting the results of a db query in php and return it thru ajax in a json array, but when I try to access the data it gives me data as 'undefined'
why is that happening?

Here is my php code:

```
<?php
    $tipo_prod= $_POST['tipo_prod'];
    $conn = oci_connect("admin", "admin", "localhost/XE");
    $query = "SELECT COD_PRODUCTO, NOMBRE FROM PRODUCTO WHERE COD_TIPO_PROD=" . $tipo_prod;
    $exec= oci_parse($conn, $query);
    oci_execute($exec);
    //Check connection!!!
    $exec= oci_fetch_array($exec);
    echo json_encode($exec);
?>
```

And my ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
    url : "trae_producto.php", 
    type : "POST",
    data: {"tipo_prod" : tipo_prod},
    success : function(data){
    data = JSON.stringify(data);
    $.each(data, function(index, value){
        $('#producto').append("<option value='" + value.COD_PRODUCTO + "'>" + value.NOMBRE + "</option>"); 
    });
}});
```

Comment: as first step inspect the value returned from server using browser network tab or by logging the value of `data` in the console in the success handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try doing::

```
$.ajax({
    url : "trae_producto.php", 
    type : "POST",
    data: {"tipo_prod" : tipo_prod},
    dataType: "json",
    success : function(data){        
    $.each(data, function(index, value){
        $('#producto').append("<option value='" + value.COD_PRODUCTO + "'>" + value.NOMBRE + "</option>"); 
    });
}});
```

try adding Content-Type header in your PHP code, like:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($exec);
```

Added:
do something like

```
while($data = oci_fetch_array($exec)) {
 $out[] = $data;
}
echo json_encode($out);
```

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't send me anything,even if I use console.log()

Comment: @montjoile what do you see for console.log(data); ...?

Comment: I use: console.log(data[0].NOMBRE);  out of $.each
and console.log(value.NOMBRE);  inside the $.each and it doesn't appear anything in the console

Comment: @montjoile try doing just console.log(data); before your $.each.. to see what you get for data

Comment: @montjoile see added answer and verify if you are actually getting results in $exec variable in PHP side..!

Comment: when I run my php file with firebug it gives me:
Warning: json_encode(): type is unsupported, encoded as null in line 11, which is "echo json_encode($exec);"

what does that mean???

Comment: @montjoile that means you are trying to encode resource, see my added answer

Comment: you're welcome..:) Btw if it worked as you expected , you could mark it as Accepted Answer.. :)

Comment: just one thing more, could you explain the solution? I don't understand why it works

Comment: yes, it was not working at first because there was nothing but just the resource reference in your $exec variable, due to which json_encode was not able to perform the required action, you need to fetch the result from your $exec resource reference only after which it can be json_encode()'ed, that's what is being done with the above code i added..

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    url : "trae_producto.php", 
    type : "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {"tipo_prod" : tipo_prod},
    success : function(data){
    /* data = JSON.stringify(data); */
    $.each(data, function(index, value){
        $('#producto').append("<option value='" + value.COD_PRODUCTO + "'>" + value.NOMBRE + "</option>"); 
    });
}});
```

I don't know what's your real return from PHP script but if it assumed as correct, the AJAX seems have some flaws.

1. JSON.stringify will make your object to string type so the jQuery iterator won't work.
2. use "dataType" attribute to inform AJAX it will getting JSON object

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to turn the result that it gives you into JSON. jQuery parses it already for you, just remove the line for JSON.stringify.

```
 $.ajax({
     url : "trae_producto.php", 
     type : "POST",
     data: {"tipo_prod" : tipo_prod},
     success : function(data){
        $.each(data, function(index, value){
            $('#producto').append("<option value='" + value.COD_PRODUCTO + "'>" + value.NOMBRE + "</option>"); 
        });
     }
 });
```

Comment: It gives me: "TypeError: invalid 'in' operand e"

Answer (score 0):

At first, debug through firebug whether you are getting a JSON object, as well as your server is sending data. Then, instead of `data = JSON.stringify(data);`, you can use `data = JSON.parse(data);`